# best way for a c# developer to break into Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a full time c# developer, but I want to get more into Python. At the same time, I have a friend who will learn it with me, he however has no programming knowledge.

I was thinking about starting with some visual programming. I.E: having buttons, labels and text boxes on a form.

Does some kind of IDE exist which allows you to very quickly build a Tkinter app in Python, and compile run it for Windows?

In a nutshell I'm trying to find something with similar functionality to MS Visual Studio.

If not, would Iron Python running in VS be what I need to start with?

Answer (score 1):

> Does some kind of IDE exist which allows you to very quickly build a Tkinter app in Python, and compile run it for Windows?

There's nothing similar to VisualStudio for building tkinter interfaces, although some visual designers do exist take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693939/need-a-gui-builder-for-tkinter-python) question.

Keep in mind that a lot of professional python developers use nothing but a text editor even on huge codebases.

You don't have to compile your python programs in order to run them. The interpreter automagically compiles them to bytecode when you run them.

Now. I suggest you don't start with GUI programming in python just yet. But if you insist PyQT is much better than tkinter.

I'd probably start with a small RSS agregator, a small web page crawler that downloads all the images from a website with a CLI. Then move on to web and GUI apps.

Comment: why do you say PyQT is "much better"? Tkinter is built-in, and it's extremely beginner-friendly. That's all this person needs at this point. As beginners, they don't need to get dragged into the "my toolkit is better than your toolkit" war.